# iOS 16 – Can I choose when the "Screen Time weekly report" is delivered?

Tags: ios, notifications, screen-time

I'm on an iPhone with iOS 16.2.

Every Monday, I receive a notification that points to the ["weekly Screen Time report"](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-a-report-of-your-device-use-iph53eb0d0e3/ios) for the previous week. It seems to pop up with remarkable consistency around 9:30 AM.

I'm happy to get the notification and review my phone usage, but I don't get why and how the app came up with this specific time.

*Can I choose a different time* for this weekly notification, say, every Monday at 8AM?